# Sidebar area not floating correctly

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to get a sidebar to appear correctly in Wordpress framework with some effort here but I am almost their but the sidebar needs to appear to the right of the text of the blog just beside the title to the far right

You can view the page in question here  http://kvalixhu.digitalthinkersni.co.uk/blog/

Image for how I want it to display

https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/369625/9zqAVkxFA4iFRBTqA1E5mw20uuWOqgs8/

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: BlogPosts
*/
         get_header();


        ?>
<style>

#title_wrapper{
width:488px;
}

h2{
    font-size:18px;
    font-familly:verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    line-height:16px;
    display:inline;
    padding:2px;

}
#dateinfo{
    font-weight:bold;


}
</style>
        <div id="main-content" class="main-content">

        <?php
        if (is_front_page()) {
            get_template_part('featured-content');
        }
        ?>

        <div class="full-width page-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <h1>Blog</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row  show-for-medium-up">
            <div class="column breadcrumb">
                <?php
        if (function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb')) {
            //echo __('Home',TD) . ' > ';            
            yoast_breadcrumb('<span id="breadcrumbs">', '</span>');
        }
        ?>
           <?php
        if (function_exists('bcn_display_list_multidim_children')) {
        ?><ul class="breadcrumbs">
                <?php
            bcn_display_list_multidim_children();
        ?>
               </ul><?php
        }
        ?>
           </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="row">


                    <div class="column small-12 product">    
                               <?php
        $logo = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'logo', true);
        ?>

                      <div class="post-list" style="width:80%;">
            <?php
        $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&offset=$debut');
        foreach ($myposts as $post):
            setup_postdata($post);
        ?>
             <div id="dateInfo" style="float:right;">
<?php the_date('Y.m.j'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<?php comments_number( '0 hozzászólás', '1 hozzászólás', '% hozzászólás' ); ?>.
</div>


             <div id="title_wrapper">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

</div>


                  <div class="thumbnail" style="float: left; margin: 10px">  
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( array( 395, 195 ) ); ?>
                    <div class="thumbnail-arrow"></div>
                </div>

            <!-- Display movie review contents -->
            <div class="entry-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        <div>

            <?php


        endforeach;
        ?>

            <div class="column small-6 product " style="float:right;">
        <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Right Sidebar')) : ?>
[ do default stuff if no widgets ]
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
        <hr />


        </div>

        </div> </div>
        </div>


        <?php

        get_footer();
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that you would want to do is move the "sidebar div" outside of the post-list div, and adding "float:left;" to the post-list div.
Also, add a width to the sidebar div with "width: 20%;" to make sure it fits.

The answer is a bit vague but hopefully you understand.

Hopefully this helps

Comment: I tried that their but its not giving the desired effect its still staying at the bottom of the hr

Comment: Yes, sorry, you need to give the sidebar div a width of 20%

Comment: Done that mate but its still refusing to float to the right grrr hate css

http://kvalixhu.digitalthinkersni.co.uk/blog/

Comment: Okay, give me a second to set it up like it works for me and I'll post you the code I use

Comment: there's a syntax error in the float: left on your page. If you remove the ' .. then you're golden

Comment: Thank you edit question above just then ill mark as answer

Comment: SO = Stack Overflow. Welcome to it :) Noticed you are a new user, so a welcome is in order

Comment: I mean where abouts is the float left error cannot find it in source

Comment: Sorry, it's on the post-list div
    **float: left';**

There's an extra **'** there

Comment: Can i ask also what may the issue be here the titles are not floating correct to a new line when more than one post ?. http://kvalixhu.digitalthinkersni.co.uk/blog/

Comment: Of course..
After you have used floats, you need to clear them.. you can do that in a few ways, but the easiest way to begin with (not the cleanest nor the most professional way) is to add a div right before the title_wrapper that goes something like this
**<div style="clear:both;"></div>**